# Using XML::Twig failure due to Expat module

Tags: perl, xml-twig

I am using a Perl source that I compile and use dll of it in my tool.
In it I am trying to embed XML::Twig module in perl statically.

XML::Twig is dependent on XML::Parse which need XML::Parse::Expat.
I am using Twig module function in my scripts as below:

```
    my $FILENAME = "C:\\log.xml";
    my $twig= new XML::Twig;

    $twig->parsefile( $FILENAME);    # build the twig
    my $root= $twig->root;           # get the root of the twig (stats)
    my @players= $root->children;    # get the player list
```

This usage internally calls Parser module which call Expat which throws error as Undefined subroutine &XML::Parser::Expat::ParserCreate called at Expat.pm line 77.

I have dynamically linked perl dll to my tool and also linked Expat.lib
Can you please tell if the problem that I am getting is because of some way to Export ParserCreate function which resides in Expat.lib ?